# Microsoft.AspNet.Identity, use email as username

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I am using Asp.Net Webforms application. I used Microsoft.AspNet.Identity for authentication. I want use user's email address as username. But it doesn't let.
can you help me please?

Comment: Can you provide the error, context?

Comment: the error is "User name is invalid, can only contain letters or digits."

Comment: public AccountController(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
{
    UserManager = userManager;
    var userValidator = UserManager.UserValidator as UserValidator<ApplicationUser>;
    userValidator.AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = false;
}

Comment: this one is the way that I can solve this problem. But it is for MVC and I dont know how can I use this in Webforms application

Comment: I dont use MVC and I dont have AccountController.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably the problem is the use of non-alphanumeric characters in username. If so use this

```
UserManager.UserValidator = new UserValidator<TUser>(UserManager) { 
                                      AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = false }
```

Comment: where should I copy this code?

Comment: @user3013083 Add this code to the constructor of
public AccountController(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)

Comment: But there is no AccountController in ASP.NET WEBFORMS Application

Comment: @user3013083 You can use a custom membership provider

Comment: @user3013083 Who the f' still uses asp.net Webforms? It's complete junk.